# pandas mapping function to transform data using dictionary

Tags: pandas

please help friends.

I want to use mapping  to  match the age of student and identify them in category adult or child by comparing it with a dictionary 'dlist' containing age 1 to 18 as child and age 19 to 60 as adult..

```
# making Data Frame
age=np.random.randint(1,50,5,int)
name=['kashif', 'dawood', 'ali', 'zain', 'hamza']
df5=pd.DataFrame({'name':name,
                   'age':age})
# making dictionary
dlist={range(1,18):'child' , range(19,50):'adult'}

# now maping dictionary with data frame 'age' column elements to add status adult if age greater than 18 using dictionary
df5['Status']=df5.age.map(dlist)
```

but it returns the data frame with column name 'Status' but NAN values (instead of adult or child)

kindly ignore my English if there are mistakes. i m not a native speaker of english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, you are allowed to use ranges as dict-keys, but it does not work the way you seem to think. For example

```
print(dlist[1])
```

will give you a key-error, since the key `1` does not exist in `dlist`, however

```
print(dlist[range(1,18)])
```

will work, since you have a key that is `range(1,18)`. This means that you can not use your `dlist` the way you want in the `map`-function

To make use of your dict, with ranges as keys, you should instead use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df5['Status'] = df5['age'].apply(
    lambda x: next((v for k, v in dlist.items() if x in k), 'NA')
)
```

Where `[v for k, v in dlist.items() if x in k]` gives you a list of all values in your dict, if `x` is in `k` (which is a range). The `next()`-function gets the next value (i.e. the first value) in that list (but it also works on iterators, and thats why `[]` can be omitted. `NA` is the default value for `next()` if no `next` exists. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

You should howevr note that range(1,18) [does NOT include 18](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). So with this code, the age 18 will give you Status = 'NA'

Comment: thanks for explaining.  i was thinking that i m not using dictionary correctly.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept the answer that helped you solved the problem (if it was this answer, or another one). That way other people finding this question when searching knows which answers solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve by using `np.where`

```
df5['status'] = np.where((df5['age']>=1) & (df5['age']<=18), 'child', 'adult')
print(df5)
  name  age status
kashif   15  child
dawood   11  child
   ali   33  adult
  zain   21  adult
 hamza   31  adult
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my personal preference when working with pandas. I always use `cut()` method of pandas with a list of labels and bins to create a categorical variable:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
# making Data Frame
np.random.seed(41)
age=np.random.randint(1,50,5,int)
name=['kashif', 'dawood', 'ali', 'zain', 'hamza']
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'age':age})

# create a bin
bins = [0, 18, 50]
# create a bin label
label_list = ['adult', 'old']
# create a new column with bin and label
df['status'] = pd.cut(df.age, bins, labels=label_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

use np.select

```
#specify conditions
conditions=[(df5['age']<=18),
        (df5['age']>18)& (df5['age']<=50)]
#specify column output based on conditions 
choices = ['child','adult'] #you can also specify numbers as well here
#create status column based on conditions
df5["status"] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```